# Getting some experience with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I recently learned asp.net webforms and  looking to get some experience under my belt using it.I found a website that provided some exercises here:

[asp.net exercises](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/free-exercises/asp.net-4.0-c-sharp.htm)

There weren't that many and I managed to finish them all.Are there any other website or books with similar exercises or tasks that could help me get some experience in using asp.net?

Comment: Have about building your own project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of exercises to find on the internet, take a look at these websites:

- [Asp.net: Web Forms Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/web-forms)

Free Web Forms Video Training from Pluralsight:

- [Introduction to ASP.NET](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-01&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)
- [ASP.NET Web Forms Features](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-02&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)
- [Working with Data](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-03&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)
- [Entity Framework](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-04&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)
- [Master Pages](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-05&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)
- [Javascript and Ajax](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-06&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)
- [Security](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-07&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)
- [Using ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-08&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)
- [Web Deployment](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=fritz-onion&name=webforms-09&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)

I also recommend to follow some blogs like:

- [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/)
- [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/)
- [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/)
- [Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/)
- [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/Default.aspx)
- [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/)
- [Scott Mitchell](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/)
- [Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/)